# Telegram Bot API reply to message return "Bad Request: can't parse reply parameters JSON object"

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing bot that should reply in discussion thread of a channel.
However I get this responce:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 400,
  "description": "Bad Request: can't parse reply parameters JSON object"
}
```

The data of the request was

```
{
  "method": "post",
  "payload": {
    "method": "sendMediaGroup",
    "chat_id": <CHAT ID OF THE CHANEL>,
    "media": [ <SOME MEDIA> ],
    "reply_parameters": {
      "message_id": <MESSAGE ID>,
      "chat_id": <CHAT ID OF THE CHANEL>
    },
    "disable_notification": true
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

**EDIT**

running the JS:

```
const botToken = "the actual token";
const botSendMessageUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botToken + "/sendMessage";
const channelId = -1001234567894;
const discussionId = -1001234567890;
var res = await fetch(botSendMessageUrl + `?chat_id=${channelId}&text=message`).then(r=>r.json());
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));

var messageId = res.result.message_id;
res = await fetch(botSendMessageUrl + `?chat_id=${discussionId}&text=message&reply_parameters={message_id: ${messageId}, chat_id:${channelId}}`).then(r=>r.json());
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

the first fetch was successful:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "message_id": 85,
    "sender_chat": {
      "id": -1001234567894,
      "title": "title",
      "type": "channel"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": -1001234567894,
      "title": "title",
      "type": "channel"
    },
    "date": 1705426331,
    "text": "message"
  }
}
```

but the second got error:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 400,
  "description": "Bad Request: can't parse reply parameters JSON object"
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. See [ask] about creating a [mre].

Comment: I edited the question, add some code example. hopping it's clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `{}` in a `fetch` like that, Telegram won't be able to parse that as the error shows.

Rather use something like `URLSearchParams` in combination with `JSON.stringify` for the nested object.

This should get you stared:

```js
const text = 'Hello world!';
const channelId = 123;
const discussionId = 456;
const messageId = 789;

const params = new URLSearchParams({
    text,
    chat_id: discussionId,
    reply_parameters: JSON.stringify({
        message_id: messageId,
        chat_id: channelId
    })
})

fetch(botSendMessageUrl + '?' + params.toString())
    .then(j => j.json())
    .then(k => console.log(k));
```